# Circular array applied to an empty that is not in the world center

Tags: modifiers

I'm modeling a knob so I want to copy an object along cylinder (which is not in the world center) faces. I've watched many tutorials and all of them show how to do that if an empty is in the world center. I cannot achieve the desired effect if it's not. I noticed that copied objects are getting closer to the cylinder when I move the empty closer to the world center (image #3) but I still cannot understand what should I do to get the array on the cylinder's surface. Could you please help me with this?

The original object's origin is in the center of the cylinder. My Blender version is 2.82. All transformations are applied to the original object.

[image: the cylinder and the original object]
[image: the first array item is too far away]
[image: this happens when I move the empty to the world center]

Comment: Try parenting the empty and the object you want to use the array on in another empty. The control empty will then use the local offset from the parent empty and you can place that parent empty in the center of the cylinder.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it didn't work for me, unfortunately. Or, maybe, I didn't get you right. More to that, I've found a video where a guy does this with only one empty but I cannot understand how due to the fact it's too fast (https://youtu.be/osAU4McsvWY?t=1126)...